# What does a caret (^) do in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the caret (^) doing in the following SQL Server query?

```
SELECT 1^2,  1^3;
```

which gives the results:

```
3   2
```

I came across this before I found the SQUARE() function.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The caret (^) translates to the XOR operator, which is a "bitwise exclusive or". In plain english it means "either, but not both". Here's what it does:

```
decimal 1 = binary 001                     decimal 1 = binary 001
XOR                                        XOR
decimal 2 = binary 010                     decimal 3 = binary 011
=                                          =
decimal 3 = binary 011                     decimal 2 = binary 010
```

More info on the MSDN page for [bitwise operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

```
   3^2
   =
   000011  (3)
   xor
   000010  (2)
   =  
   000001  (1)
   =
   1
```

Comment: I think your plus sign is misleading - this isn't do adding, this is XORing the numbers.  Your setup works for the first example of 1^2 but would fail on the second example of 1^3

Comment: @Dave McClelland Thanks for the comment, I was thinking likewise.

Comment: I must have ninja posted between your first post and your revision.  Looks good now :)