# Why does SELECT 2^3 return 1 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bitwise-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does a caret (^) do in a SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769200/what-does-a-caret-do-in-a-sql-query)

Why does SELECT 2^3 return 1 in SQL Server ?

The above was an interview question I came across and could not get why it returns 1.

After googling a bit, I found out that it is a bitwise operator. But I still couldn't understand why 1 is an output.

I have basic knowledge of queries, stored procedure and T-SQL. Can anybody please explain to me:

1. How do I get 1 in SELECT 2^3 ?
2. What is the practical use of such operators ?

And if there is a practical use, then what are the best practices while using such operators

Comment: Not sure why but `SELECT POW(2,3)` should give you `8`!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because ^ is [XOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190277.aspx) operator.

Truth table for XOR

```
-------
|^|1|0|
-------
|1|0|1|
-------
|0|1|0|
-------
```

In another words in result we have have one only when two bits are different.

```
1 ^ 1 = 0
1 ^ 0 = 1
0 ^ 1 = 1
0 ^ 0 = 0
```

For You case it its

```
binary - decimal
00010  - 2
00011  - 3
---------- ^
00001  - 1
```

More about [XOR gate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190277.aspx)

**Usage**

For example for [mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29) ([bitwise operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188725.aspx)) handling or cryptography.

Answer (score 11):

```
a b a^b
-------
0 0  0
0 1  1
1 0  1
1 1  0

2   0b10
3   0b11
--------
2^3 0b01 = 1
```

The real practical use is to toggle bits when used as flags.

Comment: In which scenarios are they used and how do they effect performance of a query, in which it is used and alternatives(if any) for them.

Comment: They are used when you want to toggle bits used as flags, or when you want to implement some algorithm that uses it. Other than those, you can ignore it.

Answer (score 6):

it's the **Bitwise Exclusive OR**.

The truth tables for OR and XOR (exclusive OR) are different. OR means 'If either of these inputs are true, the output is true'. XOR means 'If one or the other, but not both of the inputs are true, the output is true'

OR truth table:
false OR false = false
true OR false = true
false OR true = true
true OR true = true

XOR truth table:
false XOR false = false
true XOR false = true
false XOR true = true
true XOR true = false

So what the query is doing is converting each input into binary, then doing an XOR on each bit.
2 ^ 3:

```
    00000010 (2) 
XOR
    00000011 (3)
= 
    00000001
```

Comment: I remember XOR as `if both the inputs are the same then false else true` and for OR as `if both the inputs are false then false else true` ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
2 in binary = 10
3 in binary = 11
^ bitwise (XOR)

10 XOR 11 = 01
01 binary = 1 in decimal
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to use "power" function? :)

POWER
Returns the value of the given expression to the specified power.

Syntax
POWER ( numeric_expression , y )

```
select power(2, 3)
```

returns 8...

PS: Using ^ operator (and other bitwize operators) is need when you want to interpret some numeric fields as "mask" data and perform operations using bits from numbers.

Comment: No its not "select power(2, 3)". It is "select 2^3".

Comment: OK then. Usually some students try to use "^" instead of "power", so I just suppose that it is it. :)